# How to select rows from a group using a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains data in this format.

```
ProductID   ShipId
11          1
11          2
11          3
22          1   
22          2
33          1
33          2
```

Now I want only the distinct product ids where ship id 3 is not associated.
Output should be

22,33 only.

I have used this query but it throws error.

```
Select distinct productid from X_product_ship group by productid having shipid <> 3
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery in the where clause to exclude the products that has a shipid of three.

```
select distinct P1.ProductID
from dbo.X_product_ship as P1
where P1.ProductID not in (
                          select P2.ProductID
                          from dbo.X_product_ship as P2
                          where P2.ShipId = 3
                          )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e51b/1)

Or you could get creative in the having clause using a case statement.

```
select P.ProductID
from dbo.X_product_ship as P
group by P.ProductID
having max(case when P.ShipId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e51b/2)

Comment: you left out NOT EXISTS as an option :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e51b/4 but go with the HAVING approach

Comment: @Mikael Is this not sufficient? `select P.ProductID
from dbo.X_product_ship as P
group by P.ProductID
having max(P.shipID) <> 3`

Comment: @user3427540 Not if you also can have rows with shipID = 4. `max()` will then return the 4 and the ProductID will be returned even if there is a ShipID of 3 for that ProductID.